# Yii2 - Oracle performance issue when getting one row by a unique field

Tags: yii2, oracle12c

I'm using Yii2, version **2.0.35**, apaoww/yii2-oci8 version **1.0.**0 to connect to **Oracle DB**

I have a table that stores users, it's about 8 millions rows. This table has an **unique index** by "phonenumber"

I got a performance issue when trying to get a user by phone number, as below:

```
$user = User::findOne(['phonenumber' => 'xxxx']);
```

It takes about 4s, but when I try to select directly in DB, it runs very fast.

Finally, I use Java, it can select very fast.
I'm really disappointed with Yii2 and using Java is the best solution currently to solve this problem :(

**So, My questions are:**

1. Did you have the same issue with Yii2?
2. What happened in this case? Is it fixed in the new Yii2 version?

Answer (score -1):

Is there an index on phonenumber in the User table? If not, then you should fix it and check the speed of the request.

Comment: Yes, I said it in the article. Do you have any suggestions?